6V 3W solar panel and to charge phone through a DC converter XL6009E1 via a 12V 2A car charger
I have a 6V 3W solar panel and want to charge phone with it, i have tried a dc converter XL6009E1 via a 12V 2A car charger it shows charging but battery power did not increase
I am scared of using the dc converter because I am not sure of the output.

6V 3W is only 0.5A.  In theory, if you step it up to 12V, then back down to 5V, then that could give 0.6A.  But that assumes 100% efficiency at each conversion, which isn't ever going to happen.
So your solar panel is too small to generate enough power to charge a phone.
And if the 12V car charger tells the phone that it can charge at 2A, then it will fail as soon as the phone starts to charge.
